# Indefinite Provisioning of EMR Cluster with Segue in R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I am trying to use the `R` package called `Segue` by JD Long, which is lauded as the ultimate in simplicity for using R with AWS by a book I read called "**Parallel R**".

However, for the 2nd day in a row I've run into a problem where I initiate the creation of a cluster and it just says `STARTING` indefinitely.

I tried this on OS X and in Linux with clusters of sizes 2, 6, 10, 20, and 25. I let them all run for at least 6 hours. I have no problem starting a cluster in the AWS EMR Management Console, though I have no clue how to connect `Segue`/`R` to a cluster that was started in the Management Console instead of via `createCluster()`.

So my question is -- is there either some way to trouble shoot the provisioning of the cluster or to bypass the problem by creating the cluster manually and somehow getting `Segue` to work with that?

Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

> library(segue)
>
> Loading required package: rJava
>
> Loading required package: caTools
>
> Segue did not find your AWS credentials. Please run the setCredentials() function.
>
> setCredentials("xxx", "xxx")
>
> emr.handle <- createCluster(numInstances=10)

```
STARTING - 2013-07-12 10:36:44
STARTING - 2013-07-12 10:37:15
STARTING - 2013-07-12 10:37:46
STARTING - 2013-07-12 10:38:17
```

.... this goes on for hours and hours and hours...

[image: management console]

### **UPDATE**##: After 36 hours and many attempts that failed, this began working (**randomly...**) when I tried it with 1 node. I then tried it with 10 nodes and it worked great. To my knowledge nothing changed locally or on AWS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question on behalf of the AWS support rep who gave me the following belated explanation:

> The problem with the EMR creation is with the Availability Zone specified (us-east-1c), this availability zone is now constrained and doesn't allow the creation of new instances, so the job was trying to create the instances in a infinite loop.
>
> You can see information about constrained AZ here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-regions-availability-zones
>
> "As Availability Zones grow over time, our ability to expand them can become constrained. If this happens, we might restrict you from launching an instance in a constrained Availability Zone unless you already have an instance in that Availability Zone. Eventually, we might also remove the constrained Availability Zone from the list of Availability Zones for new customers. Therefore, your account might have a different number of available Availability Zones in a region than another account."
>
> So you need to specify another AZ, or what I recommend is not specify any AZ, so EMR is going to be able to select any available.

I found this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/segue-r/GBd15jsFXkY

on Google Groups, where the topic of availability zones came up before. The zone that was set as the new default in that thread was the zone causing problems for me. I am attempting to edit the source of Segue.

Answer (score 1):

Jason, I'm the author of Segue so maybe I can help.

Please look under the details section in the lower part of the AWS console and see if you can determine if the bootstrap sequences completed. This is an odd problem because typically an error at this stage is pervasive across all users. However I can't reproduce this one.